# Loose filament hairs on print

Tags: ultimaker-cura, creality-cr-10

I'm printing a vase using Spiralize Outer Contour.

On each print, I run into the issue you see in the photos. There's random 'hairs' of filament spread across the print.

I think it is because there might be some filament building up on the nozzle at some point. And when it becomes too much, the accumulated mess of filament touches and sticks to the print, comes loose from the nozzle, and is partly blown to the side by the part fan.

Is that a common cause for this issue?

If so, what would be a logical fix to the issue? I've tried difference layer heights, I've manually bed levelled many times, and it also happens with automatic bed levelling.

Setup:

- Printer: Creality 3D CR-10S Pro V2
- Extruder: Bondtech DDX v3 Direct Drive
- Hotend: Slice Engineering Mosquito Magnum

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried reducing the flow slightly?

Comment: @towe Not yet, good one, I'll try that on the next attempt.